# trigger click event of div manually

Tags: jquery, events

i have a div which has many divs.when binding the divs i create click event for each item like below

```
    jQuery.each(opts.items, function (i, item)
                    {
                        var image = opts.image;
                        jQuery('jQuery('<div class="' + opts.optionClassName + opts.controlId + '" id="' + item.key + '" ><img src="' + image + '" alt="checkbox" />' + item.value + '</div>')
                                .click(function ()
                                {')
                                        .click(function ()
                                        {

    //code goes here

    }
```

when the div is clicked in UI this gets triggered, but when i try to do it manually it does not get triggered. any help on how to trigger would be great.
i hardcoded the div values and tried to call but it is of no use.

```
   var id1 = 'Car';
    var id2 = 'Bus';
    $('div class="CList" id="1" >' + id1 + '</div>').trigger('click');
    $('div class="CList" id="3" >' + id2 + '</div>').trigger('click');
```

even this

```
    var id1 = 'Car';
    var id2 = 'Bus';
    $('div class="CList" id="1" >' + id1 + '</div>')[0].click();
    $('div class="CList" id="3" >' + id2 + '</div>')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you have aren't valid selectors. You're passing something that's almost HTML to the jQuery function so it doesn't know what to do with it.

If the IDs for your elements are `1` and `3`, then you'd just do:

```
$('#1, #3').trigger('click');
```

Perhaps a better way, if you want to simulate the click on each of them, is to iterate over your collection again:

```
jQuery.each(opts.items, function(i, item) {
    $('#' + item.key).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: :i am trying $('#1 .optionCheckboxURegionList').trigger('click'); let me get back to you if it works.. i think i even tried this before i did like above.

Comment: @G-- That looks for an element with that class **inside** of the element with the ID of 1. However, your element with an ID of 1 *has* that class: take out the space. The class selector is pretty unnecessary though, there should only ever be one element with a particular ID on your page.

Comment: you mean to say $('#1.optionCheckboxURegionList').trigger('click'); with no space between id and class.?

Comment: @G-- Yes, the space means "inside of", no spaces means "AND". You want the element with ID of 1 AND having that class, not the element having that class that's inside of an element with ID of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Get you Elements via Jquery and use trigger function ;)

```
$("#yourdesiredselementsid").trigger("click");
```

Comment: @Igle: i am binding click event for entire div.and even if i hardcode the existing div and trigger click event it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Give your outer div a class name

```
  <div class="display">
   <div id="1"></div>
   <div id="2"></div>
    </div>
```

And then

```
$('.display').on('click','div',function (e) {

alert('hey');
  });
```