# HTML input onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box (FieldTest) on HTML page, and a javascript function that invoked when the value of the input box is changed.

When changing the value of the input box manually, then the function is triggered, but when I change that by jquery  $("#FieldTest").val('Some Text'); Then the onchange function is not triggered!

Any Idea??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trigger click event of div manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786107/trigger-click-event-of-div-manually)

Comment: You'll need to trigger the event manually if you change the value of the element via jQuery / JS.

Comment: Has already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/4500083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onchange event is dispatched only if the user is typing in the input and the input loses focus.
To dispatch it manually, simply use this line:

$(“#FieldTest”).change();

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value programmatically will not trigger an onChange event. You will have to create and dispatch one manually.